# Load a HTML file with NG-Grid in a div using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a HTML file where on click of a hyperlink i need to load another HTML file in a DIV inside the first HTML file. Can i achieve this in AngularJS? If so how? Also there is ng-Grid in the HTML. here is the code am trying:

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ghLaC7hWnUS2oqCKaiU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about hyperlinks is that they generally map a HTTP GET request to a reusable url.

If you use `$routeProvider` and

```
<a href="#/table">table</table>
<div ng-view="table"></div>
```

like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZlVZZYw9wQIDza7NeVtu?p=preview

You can ctrl-click the the link, open the link in new tabs/windows or share the link.

Comment: But there is ng-grid in the HTML am trying to load. HTML is getting loaded. But data in the Grid is not loading... Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ghLaC7hWnUS2oqCKaiU?p=preview

Comment: The template you include in the `#about` route, should only be a html fragment and you should probably load your table controller logic in `aboutController`, like so:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1pqGmPh4pbWJTCrOJqIQ?p=preview

Comment: what ever is there is the plunker is what i need. But if i use that am getting an error. Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDirective

Comment: Do you get `$sceProvider` error on this page: http://plnkr.co/edit/1pqGmPh4pbWJTCrOJqIQ?p=preview ?
I can't see the `$sce` service referenced anywhere in the code.

Comment: Its working now. But why is the CSS not applying for the Grid?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
<a ng-click="showAdditionalContent = true">Show</a>
<div ng-if="showAdditionalContent" ng-include="html/file.html">

</div>
```

Comment: But there is ng-grid in the HTML am trying to load. HTML is getting loaded. But data in the Grid is not loading... Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ghLaC7hWnUS2oqCKaiU?p=preview

Comment: You have problems in your code. For example you bootstrap your app for second time `app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);`.
Just don't mess your js, place it in separate file

Comment: even if i remove that piece of code its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ngBindHtml directive too.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: But there is ng-grid in the HTML am trying to load. HTML is getting loaded. But data in the Grid is not loading... Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ghLaC7hWnUS2oqCKaiU?p=preview